# Stateful Class Hook React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to make it work as an increment button:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Logon extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counter: 0
        }
    }
render(){   
        return(
               <button onClick={() => {this.state.counter = this.state.counter + 1}}> 
                       {this.state.counter}
               </button>
        );
 }
```

Comment: You need to be calling this.setState. This is covered in e.g. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You need to call the `setState` to set the value of state in React.

<button onClick={() => {this.setState({counter: counter+1})}> 
   {this.state.counter}
</button>
```

Refer [State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) in React js